# Consumir valores de um webservice

Tags: java, web-service, query

Não tenho qualquer conhecimento no uso de `webservice`, e preciso de usar um agora para consumir dados de uma base de dados(Normalmente ia buscar os dados diretos a base de dados, mas neste caso o admin não autorizou, disse que a única maneira era disponibilizar um `webservice`).

Então tenho uma pagina em `PHP` com varios nomes de funções:

Exemplo:

```
Lista_produtos
```

Duvida: Como crio um cliente em `JAVA` que consuma esses valores? Podem disponibilizar algum código de exemplo?

**edit**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você deve ler o wsdl criado pelo webservice e criar uma interface no seu projeto que tenha acesso aos métodos que você precisa. Para isso você necessita (pelo menos nesse caso) do apache cxf. Com isso basta utilizar o comando

```
[caminho]\apache-cxf-2.2.7\bin>wsdl2java -p [pacote que será criado] -d "[caminho onde será criado o pacote]" [seuWebservice?wsdl]
```

caso você tenhao xml na sua máquina pode substituir a url pelo caminho do xml

depois disso a chamada do método é igual a qualquer outra chamada de uma interface, segue um exemplo (aqui o webservice tem um método chamado consultarEmpresaPorId que será consumido pelo método retornando uma empresa)

```
  public Empresa consultarEmpresaPorId(Long id) {
    ConsultarEmpresaPorIdRequest request = new ConsultarEmpresaPorIdRequest();
    request.setIdEmpresa(id.intValue());
    ConsultarEmpresaPorIdResponse response = WEBSERVICE.consultarEmpresaPorId(request);
    if (response.getResultCode() == 100) {
        return response.getEmpresa();
    }
```

Comment: A tua resposta parece me a mais acertada so que estou com um problema quando tento fazer a operação de ler a wsdl, dá um erro do tipo "Use SOAP Enconding is not suported" já te aconteceu isso?

Comment: O erro de "Use SOAP Enconding is not suported" resolveu se com a instalação do plugin "JAX-RPC"

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente você precisa escolher qual o tipo de Webservice você vai criar e como vai criar.

Existe esse guia para poder criar webservices Restful e com o uso do JAX-WS:
http://www.k19.com.br/artigos/criando-um-webservice-restful-em-java/

Além disso, você pode optar por seguir esse guia muito bom do site do GUJ:
http://www.guj.com.br/articles/132

Ou, se quiser algo rápido, você pode disponibilizar um Stateless Session Bean como um webservice, bastando anotá-lo com a tag @WebService:

```
@Stateless  
@WebService  
public class MyWebService {  
   public double sum(double a, double b) {  
       return a + b;  
   }  
}
```

Mais detalhes aqui:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbor.html

Comment: Eu não preciso criar o webservice, só o cliente que nesse caso será o meu programa desktop, contudo vou verificar melhor os links pode ser que tenho o que preciso

Comment: Se seu programa precisará consumir informações do webservice, você terá no mínimo que integrar ele à sua aplicação...rs
Se minhas respostas forem úteis, marca como correta! (: Valeu!

Comment: Sim tem logica, só agora é que vou testar, quanto ao marcar como certa não se preocupe...

Answer (score 0):

Parece algo bem simples. Achei o código abaixo nesse link [aqui](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-testes-jsf-web-services-design-patterns/acessando-um-web-service/#6-2-consumindo-dados-de-um-web-service).

```java
URL url = new URL("http://argentumws.caelum.com.br/negociacoes");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream content = connection.getInputStream();
List<Negociacao> negociacoes = new LeitorXML().carrega(content);
```

Comment: Obrigado por tentar ajudar mas esse código não funciona, ou pelo menos não consigo por a funcionar para o meu caso. Por acaso já tinha visto esse código, mas na ultima parte não sei o que devo por `List<Negociacao> negociacoes = new LeitorXML().carrega(content);` eu nao tenho a class negociações, nem o leitor xml(deve ser alguma lib)

Comment: aqui mostra qual a biblioteca que le o xml e como utilizar ela:
http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-testes-jsf-web-services-design-patterns/trabalhando-com-xml/#4-5-exercicios-lendo-o-xml

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o comando `wsimport` que vem no próprio JDK.

Abra o `cmd` ou `terminal` e digite `wsimport -d diretorio onde vai colocar os arquivos gerados + endereço do wsdl -Xnocompile`.

Segue um tutorial mais explicativo sobre o wsimport:
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/

Aqui, um tutorial sobre o que fazer depois do wsimport:
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/

Abraço.